# GeoTiff style layers shows up with black borders in Android

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

We uploaded a set of "floor plans" to Mapbox in GeoTiff format. While layers show up fine in Mapbox Studio, the layers appear to have a huge black background surrounding it's rendered area.

[This is how it looks in Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VijPJ.png)

[And this is how it appears in out app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55ofH.png)

We tried following the guide on documentation yet we don't understand it quite clearly:

This is the current code in charge of the map loading

```
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri("mapbox://styles/gustavjohannson/ckpzb9eop05mq18qviptlbm5d"), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this same exact issue.  Check out this link.

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/raster-transparency-issues/

It gives a useful example for android.

Basically you have to use a standard style like SATELLITE_STREETS or STREETS or whatever you choose.  But do NOT embed your map overlay into the style. You want to add your overlay as a Raster Source tileset directly in your android code.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromUri(Style.SATELLITE_STREETS)) {
loadedMapStyle.addSource(RasterSource("source-id",
        TileSet( "tileset-id", "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/HERE I PUT MY TILESET ID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidG9tbXlib21iIiwiYSI6ImNqZXg5NHZlcjB6czEyd3J5MnAxZDdieGYifQ.GUqv9fHb__o5Xq8DLdNnnA"), 256))
        loadedMapStyle.addLayer(RasterLayer("raster-layer", "source-id"))
}
```

Remember...In Mapbox Studio... Instead of creating a custom style with your map embedded, create a custom Tileset with your map and use that tileset id in your android code.